# How does a stock trade at an exchange that isn’t where it is listed?

Tags: trading, stock-exchanges, equity

For example, AAPL is listed on NASDAQ but I see that NYSE has some trading volume for that symbol. Does NYSE just act as the matching engine, fill the orders, and then report the trades to the listing exchange?

Comment: This has probably something to do with Unlisted Trading Privileges (UTP).

Comment: @tomtom, that’s what I’m asking. Does all of that have to happen with the listing exchange? Does the listing exchange have to know about it?

Comment: Nope. Different tapes. In the US stocks trade on a lot of stock exchanged in parallel. There is a uniform synchronized data feed - but it is not necessary for one exchange to know anything. Arbitrageurs will make sure the price does not go too far between exchanges.

Comment: Related: [What is the difference between a stock being "listed" on an exchange and trading on an exchange](https://money.stackexchange.com/q/123296)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can US stocks list on one stock exchange but trade on other US stock exchanges?](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/128269/can-us-stocks-list-on-one-stock-exchange-but-trade-on-other-us-stock-exchanges)

Comment: @Flux Yes both of those links were very helpful. Thank you!